# Why does this while loop not execute under the if statement?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to python and stackoverflow. I am trying to learn by working on small projects

The project is on population: In 2014 China’s population was about 1.37 billion and growing at the rate of .51% per year. In 2014 India’s population was about 1.26 billion and growing at the rate of 1.35% per year. Determine when India’s population will surpass China’s population. Assume that the 2014 growth rates will continue

The code that I have used is:

```
year = 2014
population_chn = eval(input("Enter the initial China population:")) #1.37
population_ind = eval(input("Enter the initial Indian population:")) #1.26
while population_chn == 1.37:
    population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn
    year +=1
while population_ind == 1.26:
    population_ind += 0.0135*population_ind
    year +=1
if population_ind>population_chn:
    print("Indian population will exceed china population in",year)
```

However,There is no output when i run this. What am I missing?
The output I desire is

> India's population will exceed China's population in the year 2025.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. Use `float()` to convert input to a number.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to run two completely independent loops. If you're simulating a year stepping forward, you need to change *both* populations each time, in lockstep. Right now, you increase `year` two times for every one year simulated, and have no guarantee that you do the same number of increments for each of the two populations.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<` rather than `==`, e.g. `while population_chn < 1.37:`

Comment: Each `while` loop will run at most once because you change the population variables in the loop, and they will only run at all if you enter those exact numbers.

Comment: As @CharlesDuffy says, you should compare `while population_ind < while population_chn` and increase both in the loop.

Comment: @PeterWood, yes. Or else, it's like an `if` statement.

Comment: They don't execute because your while statement only executes once. Think about what happens after 

while population_chn == 1.37:
population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn
year +=1

Is done once. What is the value of population_chn?

Answer (score 0):

in your case population_ind is never grater then population_chn this is why you will not print something

if you want to solve the problem you could try:

```
population_a = 1.37
population_b = 1.26

growing_rate_a = 0.0051
growing_rate_b = 0.0135

year = 2014
while population_a > population_b:
    year += 1
    population_b += population_b * growing_rate_b
    population_a += population_a * growing_rate_a

print(year)
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, this is a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the if statements before the while loop. You can throw all of that logic inside the while loop and update the population parameters for each year like this:

```
year = 2014
print("Enter the initial China population:")
population_chn  = eval(input())
print("Enter the initial Indian population:")
population_ind = eval(input())

while population_ind < population_chn:
    population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn
    population_ind += 0.0135*population_ind
    year +=1 
else:
    print("Indian population will exceed china population in", (year))
```

Output using 1.37 for Chn population and 1.24 as ind population:

```
Indian population will exceed china population in 2025
```

The reason why your if statement never executes is because your while statements only execute if the population is equal to the initial input. Look at these lines:

```
while population_chn == 1.37:
    population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn
    year +=1
while population_ind == 1.26:
    population_ind += 0.0135*population_ind
    year +=1
```

They will only update once because after 1 iteration your if statements are not true anymore and the population never updates after. Thus the Indian population is always less than the china population, so that statement is never executed.

Comment: why year -1 , when you give the answer ?

Comment: in the while statement you already have the necessary condition to get the  right answer, no need  to subtract 1

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you are checking for equality with 1.37 for population_chn which may be valid for first case will not work for any subsequent iteration of while loop as `population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn` changes its value. Same is the case for population_ind.
Instead you should compare value of population_chn and population_ind in the while loop and use only one loop

```
while (population_chn>=population_ind):
    population_chn += 0.0051*population_chn
    population_ind += 0.0135*population_ind
    year +=1
```